# Wagtail 500 server error with DEBUG=False

Tags: django, deployment, wagtail

I deployed the Wagtail site on Ubuntu 22.04 following digitalocean's instructions (Nginx + Gunicorn). The site works without errors when DEBUG=True, but when I put False I get Server Error (500) when going to any page.

At the same time admin panel works without errors, path to static files is correct. Error.log nginx are clean. What can be the problem? I have already tried everything.
gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user1
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user1/projectdir
ExecStart=/home/user1/projectdir/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 5 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.settings.production \
          projectname.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/user1/projectdir/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/user1/projectdir/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was due to a loose favicon